# BURN oil residue on oil stick?

Tags: engine, oil

I'm considering buying a vehicle from a auction,. they will allow you to preview the vehicles but not crank/start them up. So, your kind of taking a chance, could be good ; could be bad.

My question:
It's A 2010 Mitsubishi Endeavor. The oil stick has no oil, dry. And, it looks kinda of copper or gold color where the oil would be, almost as if its lightly burned oil residue (totally dry). I'm wondering if the motor is bad or not. Anyone have any information on this subject.

Comment: Depending how much it is, I'd buy it if the body/frame was in good shape. Then put a used motor in it. If it's low on oil it was probably abused and should probably be avoided if you're not willing to put in work.

Answer (score 1):

That gold bits could just be how the dipstick is, but I’m not sure. Burned oil on the dipstick could be an indicator of overheating, or more importantly in your case a head gasket issue. I would stay away from this unless you’re willing to put in work to swap over the motor later on.